# C# OleDbCommand Connection Properties

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, oledb

I wonder why this code didnt work since I already build a method to connect to the database and open the connection. I assume this is because I skip the use of the `OleDbCommand Connection` properties. Is it mandatory to use this properties?

My attempt to assign the `Connection()` method directly to the `OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT City FROM Employees", Connection().Open());` object also didnt work.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

class KDRM
{
static void Main()
{

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT City FROM Employees");
    Connection().Open();
    OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    while (rdr.Read())
    {

        Console.WriteLine(rdr.GetString(0));
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static OleDbConnection Connection()
{       
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Connection...";

    return conn;
}


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT City FROM Employees", Connection().Open());
```

could not work because you are trying to pass the result of Open as second parameter of the OleDbCommand constructor, but this is a void method so your code doesn't even compile.

Whenever you try to execute a command, you need to set the command connection property, to a valid connection and that connection should be open at the moment in which you execute the command.

There are established good practices to use when creating a connection and you should follow it for a good reason

```
static void Main()
{

    using(OleDbConnection cn = Connection())
    using(OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT City FROM Employees", cn);
    {
         cn.Open();
         using(OleDbDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (rdr.Read())
             {
                ....
             }
         }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

The using statement ensures that the disposable objects in your code are closed and disposed also in case of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @Steve for the `Using` statement.

Comment: It is a real life saver I use it everywhere possible because memory leaks are the subtlest bugs to find

Comment: Good advise steve, I come from the PHP background and try to learn C#/.NET, it's not easy as PHP does but its quite fun :D

Answer (score 1):

You should add this kind of code:

```
// Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
command.Connection = connection;
```

[reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: My attempt to associate `command.Connection` with my custom `Connection()` method didnt work.

Comment: so you could assign Connection() to some variable and then pass it to the Command's connection (as @Steve shown)

Comment: I even not sure, if you really need that Connection() method in your code

Comment: Thanks Boris! I modify my code like your suggestion and boom, its shows the data from the DB ;D .